# What does "Always do this" mean in Inbox by Gmail?

Tags: inbox-by-gmail

I moved a message to a tag and a notice asked me whether Google should always do this, but I didn't set a rule so I don't know what "Always" or "this" is. How does Google determine such rules whenever it shows "Always do this"?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because **Inbox by Gmail** was shut down in April, 2019, and is no longer available.

Answer (score 1):

Once you move a message under a label, you see options to **Undo** or **Always do this** in the black bar at the bottom,.

It is an option, if you want emails from this sender or email list to always go to this label, click **Always do this** in the black bar at the bottom.

For more see this: [Move emails in & out of labels](https://support.google.com/inbox/answer/6096217)